# Как реализовать связь между сущностями?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, проектирование

Есть картинки и компании.
Каждая компания может иметь много картинок. 
С виду связь один к многим.

Но, есть кейс когда привязки к компании нету.

Имеет ли смысл реализовать связь используя pivot таблицу для связи с primary key на image_id, company_id?
Или здесь достаточно просто присваивать null полю company_id в таблице images?

Доп. вопрос - что почитать чтобы таких вопросов не возникало?

Comment: Если у вас каждая картинка может быть только у одной компании, то нет смысла делать промежуточную таблицу. Лучше сбрасывать в null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дадите возможность установки null в атрибут company_id вероятнее увеличите сложности системы если это изменение и знание таких вариантов проникает в код системы в том же виде(типа if image.company == null)

если сделаете промежуточную таблицу придется делать лишние join и в зависимости от кода так же может протеч в логику системы...

Имхо чтобы максимально отстраниться от хранения данных нужно применять ddd в связке с паттерном data mapper из книги "Шаблоны корпоративных приложений" Мартина Фаулера